# Laravel Migration is not creating the table in different database

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I have this migration file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::connection('DB1')->create('feed_mappings', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id_feed')->autoIncrement();
            $table->string('id_project', 255);
            $table->string('import_field_slug', 155);
            $table->string('internal_field_slug', 155);
            $table->tinyInteger('import');
            $table->tinyInteger('custom_field')->default(0);
            $table->dateTime('date_add');
            $table->dateTime('date_upd');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('feed_mappings');
    }
};
```

And I have this config in the database.php file:

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'prefix_indexes' => true,
    'strict' => true,
    'engine' => 'InnoDB',
    'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
    ]) : [],
],

'DB1' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '8889'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'DB1'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'root'),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'prefix_indexes' => true,
    'strict' => true,
    'engine' => 'InnoDB',
    'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
    ]) : [],
],
```

Now, I have run this command :

> php artisan migrate:refresh --seed

Now, All the migration file is creating a tables on default database but I want this **feed_mappings** should go to **DB1** database.

BUT this **feed_mapping** is not going to **DB1** database. Can you tell me why?

Comment: check .env file ?

Answer (score 3):

So the issue is in your database.php file where you are using the same variables for connections 1 and 2

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    ***'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),***
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'prefix_indexes' => true,
    'strict' => true,
    'engine' => 'InnoDB',
    'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
    ]) : [],
],

'DB1' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    **'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '8889'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'DB1'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'root'),**
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'prefix_indexes' => true,
    'strict' => true,
    'engine' => 'InnoDB',
    'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
    ]) : [],
],
```

what you need to do is create separate variables for db connections e.g:

```
DB_HOST // for connection 1
DB_HOST_2 // for connection 2
```

and use these in your config files for more info visit: https://codelapan.com/post/how-to-use-multiple-database-connections-in-laravel-8

Comment: Its working but what if I need to add the same table DB1, DB2, DB3 at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

**config/database.php**

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],

        'mysql2' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST_2', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT_2', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_2', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_2', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_2', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

**Setup .env**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel_multiple_database1
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

DB_CONNECTION_2=mysql
DB_HOST_2=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT_2=3306
DB_DATABASE_2=laravel_multiple_database2
DB_USERNAME_2=root
DB_PASSWORD_2=
```

**in Model** *example Post*

```
protected $connection = 'mysql2';
```

**in migration file**

```
public function up()
 {
    Schema::connection('mysql2')->create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::connection('mysql2')->dropIfExists('posts');
}
```